# Redirect using email & password in Firebase Authentication NodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to login by using this email **admin@gmail.com** that already registered in my Firebase Authentication.

So I have write the login auth which will login if the email and password satisfied by the firebase Auth.

```
const handleLogin = (e) => { 
e.preventDefault(); 
fire.auth()
  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(() => { router.push("/") })
.catch((err) => {
    const message = err.message
    toast({
      title: "An error occured",
      position: "bottom-right",
      description: message,
      status: "error",
      duration: 2000,
      isClosable: true,
    })
  })
setEmail('')
setPassword('')
}
```

After that, I tried to modify it by using my only email for admin which is **admin@gmail.com** to redirect the page after successfully logged in to /admin dir, else if the user is not admin will redirect to "/" or "/index"

This is my modified code

```
const handleLogin = (e) => { 
e.preventDefault(); 
fire.auth()
  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(() => { 
   fire.firestore().collection("user").where("email","==","admin@gmail.com")
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        if (doc.email === 'admin@gmail.com') {
          router.push("/admin")
        } else {
          router.push("/")
        }
      })
})
.catch((err) => {
    const message = err.message
    toast({
      title: "An error occured",
      position: "bottom-right",
      description: message,
      status: "error",
      duration: 2000,
      isClosable: true,
    })
  })
setEmail('')
setPassword('')
}
```

I can't solve this problem as I'm quite new to this and been days searching for an answer. I just want to do it this way which will only **ONE ADMIN** to control the Web App and there are **MANY** users who will use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your second example looks like it should work, apart from this line

```
if (doc.email === 'admin@gmail.com') {
```

which should be

```
if (doc.data().email === 'admin@gmail.com') {
```

You could then set the where clause as

```
where("email","==",email)
```

and your code should work as intended.